# Drupal and long-polling/sockets

Tags: ajax

I'm looking for some ideas of how best to cater for the following scenario: I have a facebook-style feed on the front of a site that is updated with user content regularly, and just like facebook I want the page to update as nodes are submitted to the site.

So it looks to me like a classic use case for a bit of long-polling, or even using some of those new fang-dangled web sockets. But how am I going to integrate this with drupal?

There's no way I can have 20 let alone several hundred users long polling drupal directly - it would lock up every php process my system could provide.

I've been considering writing a tiny wee node.js program which would would handle all the long-polling connections and would watch the drupal node table directly. When updated, node would query drupal and proxy the request back to the clients. But this seems like a pretty awful solution to me.

Another idea I had was to load the current maximum node nid number along with the intial request, and then somehow also advertise this number via long-polling - if the advertised number changes, it would trigger the client to make a request. But I'm not sure how to implement this advertising.

So what other options are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, implementing comet/long polling in Drupal is a bad idea.

There already is a node.js project that you could use: [Drupal node.js integration](http://drupal.org/project/nodejs).

The design principle of that module is that node.js does not contain any logic (to avoid duplication of logic in PHP and JS) but is only reponsible for keeping a connection open to your users. You then send notifications to node.js in the usual hooks (like hook_node_save()) which forwards it to your users.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. Check out this [Drupal Voices eposide](http://www.lullabot.com/podcasts/drupal-voices-alex-barth-on-nodejs-and-express-versus-drupal) to learn more about node.js and Drupal.

Comment: So two questions about that module if you happen to know them: how is drupal pushing these updates to node? And can I push per-user information (eg. notifications on nodes they've comment on), or does that module just do broadcast?

Comment: @Torrance That would be another question. Buring questions in comments is not the best practice.